# Set placeholder for views exposed input

Tags: views, 8

I create a search section with view and I want hide label of search inputs and set placeholder for them.

Is there any section to set this?

Drupal 8

Answer (score 1):

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form'){
      $form['field-name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Placeholder Keyword');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form['#id'] == 'views_exposed_form'){
     $form['field-name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Placeholder Keyword');
   }
}
```

That's what it should be for Drupal 8.3.2

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for preprocessing since Drupal 8.5

There is a field available named *placeholder*

[image]